# Does the LIV Golf League recognize finishes in major championships?

Tags: golf

LIV Golfers Brooks Koepka and Phil Mickelson finished tied for second in the Masters tournament. Does LIV Golf recognize results in major championships?

Phil Mickelson 2023 LIV Golf results do not include the Masters.

[image: Phil Mickelson 2023 LIV Golf results]

For comparison, the PGA Tour includes Jon Rahm's Masters win in their results.

[image: Jon Rahm 2023 PGA Tour results]

Comment: My hunch is no, they dont. But I think finding proof might be hard, it seems like access to the LIV rules and regulations/players handbook is via a court order, where as you can read the PGA equivalent [here](https://qualifying.pgatourhq.com/static-assets/uploads/2022-2023-PGA-TOUR-HBandRegs-DEC%202022.pdf). Page 84 details how performances in majors contribute towards the fedex cup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the information available on the [LIV Format page](https://www.livgolf.com/liv-format), the 14 LIV events are the only ones that are included in their format.  The first 13 count for the individual title, and the 14th determines the team winner.  Non LIV events do not count for their rankings, so for example the Masters would not be included.

Their format is pretty different from the PGA format, with only 48 players at each tournament and no cut, 54 hole (3 day) tournaments, and a team overall result being determined at the end (which means all players need to play all three rounds).